# Show summary of hidden columns in gt table

Tags: r, gt

Dear Community does anyone know if there is a possibility to show the summary of hidden columns in a gt table? I want to show the total sum of frequencies for each country but dont want to show the columns by them self.

```
gt(t, rowname_col = "wrcomp_txt") |>
  tab_caption("Tabelle II: Anteil der Erwerbstätigen Bevölkerung und Frauen nach Ländern")|>
  tab_spanner_delim(delim = "_") |>
  fmt_percent(columns = starts_with("Prozent"),
              decimals = 1)|>
  fmt_percent(columns = starts_with("Frauen"),
              decimals = 1)|>
  cols_merge(columns = c("Prozent_Bulgarien", "Frauen_Bulgarien"),
             pattern = "{1} ({2})")|>
  cols_merge(columns = c("Prozent_Deutschland", "Frauen_Deutschland"),
             pattern = "{1} ({2})")|>
  cols_merge(columns = c("Prozent_Frankreich", "Frauen_Frankreich"),
             pattern = "{1} ({2})")|>
  cols_merge(columns = c("Prozent_Italien", "Frauen_Italien"),
             pattern = "{1} ({2})")|>
  cols_merge(columns = c("Prozent_Schweden", "Frauen_Schweden"),
             pattern = "{1} ({2})")|>
  cols_hide(columns = starts_with("Häufigkeiten_"))|>
  rm_spanners()|>
  grand_summary_rows(columns = starts_with(c("Häufigkeiten")),
                     fns = list(N = ~sum(.)))
```

I thought that if I use the function grand_summary I'm also able to adress also the hidden columns.